# Python 3: Catching warnings during multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, multiprocessing

### Too long; didn't read

The [`warnings.catch_warnings()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/warnings.html#available-context-managers) context manager is [not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264002/thread-safe-warnings-in-python). How do I use it in a parallel processing environment?

### Background

The code below solves a maximization problem using parallel processing with Python's [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html) module. It takes a list of (immutable) widgets, partitions them up (see [Efficient multiprocessing of massive, brute force maximization in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669600/efficient-multiprocessing-of-massive-brute-force-maximization-in-python-3)), finds the maxima ("finalists") of all the partitions, and then finds the maximum ("champion") of those "finalists." If I understand my own code correctly (and I wouldn't be here if I did), I'm sharing memory with all the child processes to give them the input widgets, and `multiprocessing` uses an operating-system-level pipe and pickling to send the finalist widgets back to the main process when the workers are done.

### Source of the problem

**I want to catch the redundant widget warnings being caused by widgets' re-instantiation after the unpickling** that happens when the widgets come out of the inter-process pipe. When widget objects instantiate, they validate their own data, emitting warnings from the Python standard `warnings` module to tell the app's user that the widget suspects there is a problem with the user's input data. Because unpickling causes objects to instantiate, my understanding of the code implies that each widget object is reinstantiated exactly once if and only if it is a finalist after it comes out of the pipe -- see the next section to see why this isn't correct.

The widgets were already created before being frobnicated, so the user is already painfully aware of what input he got wrong and doesn't want to hear about it again. These are the warnings I'd like to catch with the `warnings` module's `catch_warnings()` context manager (i.e., a `with` statement).

### Failed solutions

In my tests I've narrowed down when the superfluous warnings are being emitted to anywhere between what I've labeled below as *Line A* and *Line B*. What surprises me is that the warnings are being emitted in places other than just near `output_queue.get()`. This implies to me that `multiprocessing` sends the widgets to the workers using pickling.

The upshot is that putting a context manager created by [`warnings.catch_warnings()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/warnings.html#available-context-managers) even around everything from *Line A* to *Line B* and setting the right warnings filter inside this context does not catch the warnings. This implies to me that the warnings are being emitted in the worker processes. Putting this context manager around the worker code does not catch the warnings either.

### The code

This example omits the code for deciding if the problem size is too small to bother with forking processes, importing multiprocessing, and defining `my_frobnal_counter`, and `my_load_balancer`.

```python3
"Call `frobnicate(list_of_widgets)` to get the widget with the most frobnals"

def frobnicate_parallel_worker(widgets, output_queue):
    resultant_widget = max(widgets, key=my_frobnal_counter)
    output_queue.put(resultant_widget)

def frobnicate_parallel(widgets):
    output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # partitions: Generator yielding tuples of sets
    partitions = my_load_balancer(widgets)
    processes = []
    # Line A: Possible start of where the warnings are coming from.
    for partition in partitions:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
                 target=frobnicate_parallel_worker,
                 args=(partition, output_queue))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    finalists = []
    for p in processes:
        finalists.append(output_queue.get())
    # Avoid deadlocks in Unix by draining queue before joining processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    # Line B: Warnings no longer possible after here.
    return max(finalists, key=my_frobnal_counter)
```

Comment: > frobnicate

Thats such a wonderful word

Comment: Wish we could get more nicely-formatted questions like this.

Comment: Since you say `partitions` yields generators, is `partition` a generator in that example? If so, it isn't a pickling problem since generators can't be pickled (and the code wouldn't work on Windows).

Comment: Oops, @nneonneo. I was wrong. `my_load_balancer` actually returns a generator yielding tuples of sets. I've corrected the comment in the code.

Comment: The TL;DR is a little misleading, since what you really want is to catch warnings emitted during unpickling in `multiprocessing` workers. I take it you don't get any warnings if run this on a Linux machine?

Comment: @nneonneo: B) My *theory* is that the warnings are emitted during unpickling. Do we think that's correct? If not, then the TL;DR means what it says: Why am I having this problem? B) Since adding the validation/warning code in my widget class, I've only had access to my work machines, which run Win7. My personal machine is a Mac but I won't have access to before I have to solve this problem.

Comment: On Windows, objects are pickled in `multiprocessing` since Windows lacks `fork()` (so child processes are brand new interpreters that have to be told what to do). On Linux, arguments to process worker functions don't need to be pickled, so knowing if it works on Linux or not would help narrow down the problem. It sounds like the warnings are coming from unpickling, though.

Comment: So, you have control over the widget class? Where do you do the validation? Normally, `__init__` isn't called during unpickling.

Comment: (Believe me, I wish I could use Linux for work, rather than wait around for MINGW all day.) I do have control over the widget class, and typically `Widget.__init__` calls `Widget.validate` as the last step in instantiation. You're right about pickle not calling `__init__` (it just calls `__new__` and then fills the instance dictionary directly), hence my skepticism about this being a pickling problem.

Comment: Can you override the unpickling code of the widget just as a test to see if you still see the warnings?

Comment: @grieve, Well it appears I get one validation warning before any calls to `__reduce__` (i.e., before pickling even begins). Does that rule out the pickling theory? There are lots and lots of calls to `__reduce__` before and after all the other validation warnings.

Comment: @wkschwartz: I assumed the errors were happening at unpickle time. However \_\_reduce\_\_ is called to pickle the object. Can you look at overriding \_\_set_state\_\_? For reference: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years later, I finally have a solution (found while working on an unrelated problem). I've tested this on Python 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9.

Temporarily **patch [`sys.warnoptions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.warnoptions) with the empty list `[]`**. You only need to do this around the call to [`process.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start). `sys.warnoptions` is documented as an implementation detail that you shouldn't manually modify; the [official recommendations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter) are to use functions in the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module and to set [`PYTHONWARNINGS`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS) in [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). This doesn't work. The only thing that seems to work is patching `sys.warnoptions`. In a test, you can do the following:

```py
import multiprocessing
from unittest.mock import patch
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
with patch('sys.warnoptions', []):
    p.start()
p.join()
```

If you don't want to use [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), just patch by hand:

```py
import multiprocessing
import sys
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
old_warnoptions = sys.warnoptions
try:
    sys.warnoptions = []
    p.start()
finally:
    sys.warnoptions = old_warnoptions
p.join()
```

Comment: Sadly, this workaround doesn't work for me :( ... but setting `os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore"` does, though.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to override the `Process.run` method to use `warnings.catch_warnings`.

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> 
>>> def yell(text):
...    import warnings
...    print 'about to yell %s' % text
...    warnings.warn(text)
... 
>>> class CustomProcess(Process):
...    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
...       import warnings
...       with warnings.catch_warnings():
...          warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
...          return Process.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...    quiet = CustomProcess(target=yell, args=('...not!',))
...    quiet.start()
...    quiet.join()
...    noisy = Process(target=yell, args=('AAAAAAaaa!',))
...    noisy.start()
...    noisy.join()
... 
about to yell ...not!
about to yell AAAAAAaaa!
__main__:4: UserWarning: AAAAAAaaa!
>>>
```

or you can use some of the internals... ([`__warningregistry__`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn_explicit))

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> import exceptions
>>> def yell(text):
...    import warnings
...    print 'about to yell %s' % text
...    warnings.warn(text)
...    # not filtered
...    warnings.warn('complimentary second warning.')
... 
>>> WARNING_TEXT = 'AAAAaaaaa!'
>>> WARNING_TYPE = exceptions.UserWarning
>>> WARNING_LINE = 4
>>> 
>>> class SelectiveProcess(Process):
...    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
...       registry = globals().setdefault('__warningregistry__', {})
...       registry[(WARNING_TEXT, WARNING_TYPE, WARNING_LINE)] = True
...       return Process.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...    p = SelectiveProcess(target=yell, args=(WARNING_TEXT,))
...    p.start()
...    p.join()
... 
about to yell AAAAaaaaa!
__main__:6: UserWarning: complimentary second warning.
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The unpickling would not cause the `__init__` to be executed twice. I ran the following code on Windows, and it doesn't happen (each `__init__` is run precisely once).

Therefore, you need to provide us with the code from `my_load_balancer` and from widgets' class. At this point, your question simply doesn't provide enough information.

As a random guess, you might check whether `my_load_balancer` makes copies of widgets, causing them to be instantiated once again.

```
import multiprocessing
import collections

"Call `frobnicate(list_of_widgets)` to get the widget with the most frobnals"

def my_load_balancer(widgets):
    partitions = tuple(set() for _ in range(8))
    for i, widget in enumerate(widgets):
        partitions[i % 8].add(widget)
    for partition in partitions:
        yield partition

def my_frobnal_counter(widget):
    return widget.id

def frobnicate_parallel_worker(widgets, output_queue):
    resultant_widget = max(widgets, key=my_frobnal_counter)
    output_queue.put(resultant_widget)

def frobnicate_parallel(widgets):
    output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # partitions: Generator yielding tuples of sets
    partitions = my_load_balancer(widgets)
    processes = []
    # Line A: Possible start of where the warnings are coming from.
    for partition in partitions:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(
                 target=frobnicate_parallel_worker,
                 args=(partition, output_queue))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    finalists = []
    for p in processes:
        finalists.append(output_queue.get())
    # Avoid deadlocks in Unix by draining queue before joining processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    # Line B: Warnings no longer possible after here.
    return max(finalists, key=my_frobnal_counter)

class Widget:
    id = 0
    def __init__(self):
        print('initializing Widget {}'.format(self.id))
        self.id = Widget.id
        Widget.id += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

def main():

    widgets = [Widget() for _ in range(16)]
    result = frobnicate_parallel(widgets)
    print(result.id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```