# Display warning only once using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, python-multiprocessing

Is there a way to display a warning only once when using Pythons multiprocessing.Pool?

Simple example that illustrates the problem

```
import multiprocessing
import warnings


def func_with_warning(data):
    warnings.warn("Warning message {}".format(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [0, 1, 2]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    pool.map(func_with_warning, data)
```

Result:

```
>> /home/user/script.py:10: UserWarning: Warning message 0
warnings.warn("Warning message {}".format(data))
/home/user/script.py:10: UserWarning: Warning message 1
warnings.warn("Warning message {}".format(data))
/home/user/script.py:10: UserWarning: Warning message 2
warnings.warn("Warning message {}".format(data))
>>
```

I understand that each spawned process is like separate Python world, but maybe someone knows any trick how to display warnings in such cases only once?

Someone suggested it is duplicate of question: [Python 3: Catching warnings during multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654267/python-3-catching-warnings-during-multiprocessing). In my opinion:

- it is similar, but not the same.
- solutions there may, but **do not have to** answer my question,
- it is much more detailed and focused on some narrower scope problem of catching warnings during objects instantiations

Comment: Use a **shared** flag or a `queue`.

Comment: You should surround the work with the pool in `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175348/why-does-pythons-multiprocessing-module-import-main-when-starting-a-new-pro/14175401#14175401) for detail

Comment: @stovfl So in shared memory I need to keep track of every possible warning I am displaying and check before warning? Sounds like a lot of work and additional code, it is some solution, but only for warnings I raise myself. For warnings raised by libraries I use I think it won't work.

Comment: @Artemly I guess you tried to run the example while being on Windows, I am using Linux and when I wrote this simple example I forgot about this fork-problem you encountered. I will edit post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3: Catching warnings during multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654267/python-3-catching-warnings-during-multiprocessing)